# jQuery Datatable with PHP json_encode

Tags: jquery, json, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I tried to parse database table data to jquery data table which are dynamically change. I got following output after php's `json_encode` function

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$a= array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$a[][] = $row;
    }

    echo (json_encode($a));
```

Json output

```
[[{"id":"1","username":"test11","password":"$2y$10$NiKnEN\/ww8yGVhv3JNjSuO5FfOFSthadS2B3GcbA3KGBktAOSu6lK","role":"Administrator "}],[{"id":"2","username":"test","password":"test","role":"test"}]]
```

Then I called jquery data table ajax function as they said. here my coding for that

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": 'ab.php'
    } );
```

But ultimately display only "Loading..." text in the jquery data table `tbody` section. Why is that?

Comment: What is the problem then ?

Comment: jquery datatable is not getting data from php file

Comment: What console error you get in Browser's console ?

Comment: " TypeError: f is undefined " @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### CAUSE

Apparently you're using DataTables version 1.10. By default, this version expects data to be in certain format, see [DataTables documentation](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) for more information.

```
{
    "data": [
        // row 1 data source,
        // row 2 data source,
        // etc
    ]
}
```

#### SOLUTION

Change `$a[][] = $row;` to `$a['data'][] = $row` in your PHP to produce data in the correct format.

Answer (score 4):

If you using datatable 1.10 api, you need to create a json response like :

```
$json_data = array(
    "draw"            => intval( $_REQUEST['draw'] ),
    "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totaldata ),
    "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalfiltered ),
    "data"            => $data
);
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

- draw: we send same number which has been send by datatable at time of
  draw/request.
- recordsTotal: Total numbers of records in your table.
- recordsFiltered: Total numbers of filtered records after searching in
  your table. If you do not perform any search then recordsFiltered
  will be same as recordsTotal.
- data: Your fetched records data. You have to fetched the data as per
  start, length, search value, colomn name and sorting orders
  parameters. you can download dummy database table from here

Please refer this [link](http://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/) to know the details